# press button change text of the button loaded from edittedt but when press back button change doesn't effect and saved

Tags: android

When i press the button the text loaded from the edit text but when the back button is pressed the changed gone away mean no changed created  to the button and it show the first text so no changed saved to the button which is loaded from the edit text.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 private EditText text;
 private static Button button;
 private RadioButton radio;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);
    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    radio=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override //this api support this
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            button.setText(text.getText().toString());
            //press button and changed text of the button         
        }
    });

 }
 @Override
 protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {  
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Log.d("Text's text:" + text.getText().toString()
    + "Button:" + button.getText().toString(), null);
    //override unimplemented method
    }
 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    Log.d("Text's text:" + text.getText().toString()
    + "Button:" + button.getText().toString(), null,null);
    //override unimplemented method
 }

 @Override
 protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("Text's text:" + text.getText().toString()
    + "Button:" + button.getText().toString(), null, null); //override 
 }
 private void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("Text's text:" + text.getText().toString()
    + "Button:" + button.getText().toString(), null, null);//override
 }
 }
```

log.d show error with out not to add add arguments to match d'(String,String,Throwable)' 
but to add this then button showed no changed  effect.
log.d show error with out not to add add arguments to match d'(String,String,Throwable)' 
but to add this then button showed no changed  effect.
log.d show error with out not to add add arguments to match d'(String,String,Throwable)' 
but to add this then button showed no changed  effect.

Comment: If you press back button activity will be destroy and when you open app it will create new activity thats why not showing old value

Comment: so it is not the solution .how is it possible then that change the button text from the edit text and this changed does not created permanently.

Comment: Do you want change button text as per Edittext entered text?

Comment: yes but when this button text changed then press back button and reopen the app then the button text does not change show the first one

Comment: send me your fb id i will send you snapshot

Comment: plz mail me on parag.chauhan2010@gmail.com

Comment: see wajib rehman's answer

Answer (score 0):

use shared Preference so in this way the changed should be saved and this save will be loaded next time you want to relaunch the app.